# Can't get two tabs to align as inline block elements in header

Tags: html, css

I'm not sure why, but there are two little dashes next to two of my tabs and they're shifting everything right. It's not effecting the third tab.
Here is a JSFiddle and images

```
`http://jsfiddle.net/michaelhorstman/wL0ubv50/`
```

[image: CSS Code]

[image: HTML Code]

[image: What it looks like in the browser]

Comment: it's very hard to work with images. perhaps you could create a jsFiddle or similar that shows the problem?

Comment: I hope this is what you mean http://jsfiddle.net/michaelhorstman/wL0ubv50/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bro, in list style, there's no end anchor tag. try to add`</a>` in the each list end

Comment: like <li><a>'</a>'<li>

Comment: Ah! That fixed it! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

looks like I was missing closing anchor tags on my list items in the header!

```
       `<li> <a href="#">Hello </a></li>
        <li> <a href="#">This </a></li>
        <li> <a href="#">Test </a></li>`
```

Fixed it!